# Android phone emulator using API 23 (Google API) will NOT remount system rw

Tags: android, emulation, mount

I have tried:

adb remount
from shell: mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/vda /system

as well as various other things I found.

Wear emulator remounted just fine with adb remount.

Comment: are you on adb root ?

Comment: Yes as I said, Wear emulator works fine. I also tried su in the shell.